# How to calibrate libgazebo imu or any other imu for slam?

Tags: slam, imu, navigation, calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I found the service from the imu (/default/imu) which is a std_srv/empty service.
Is it just calling and turning the robot or what do I have to do?

I already searched and did not find any nice  tutorial on google about how to do imu calibration in ROS.
I also can't find the github libgazebo_plugins repo on google somehow
(I think this is really weired, but I know it is there so I can find it)
So I guess I might be missing something about the imu too.
Can you give me a hint what to do and how? Because the simulated Gyro is somewhat off
and slam is working only when driving forward and backward, but looks totally ugly when turning.

Actually the world is containing just a standard cube from Gazebo. That's what it looks when I drive around it.

The IMU is placed in the center between the wheels on the axis. (Diff drive)
I am also using robot_localization ukf to fuse the IMU and the Odometry.

[image: image description]

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204916/how-to-calibrate-libgazebo-imu-or-any-other-imu-for-slam?/) by [LucianTM](https://answers.ros.org/users/21714/luciantm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2015-03-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I do not believe you need to calibrate a gazebo imu plugin, for the reason that you yourself pass drift/gaussian error parameters into the plugin. If you want a completely perfect (but unrealistic) imu with no error, you can set all your error offsets to 0. However, figuring you would want this to be as close to a real world situation as possible, you will want to set the parameters to have some drift/error. If you look at Clearpath's Simulation repo's, like for example the [jackal robot](https://github.com/jackal/jackal/blob/indigo-devel/jackal_description/urdf/jackal.gazebo), you can just use there parameters.

You will also see that they arent using the libgazebo imu plugin, but instead using the imu plugin from the [hector gazebo plugins](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_gazebo_plugins) package, which i would highly recommend myself as well since i had issues with libgazebo imu plugin.

---

Originally posted by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) with karma: 1526 on 2015-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LucianTM](https://answers.ros.org/users/21714/luciantm/) on 2015-03-13**:
Hmm, I also thought about using that one, I will try ...